# Are these the same? if v1 & v2==1 and if v1==1 & v2==1

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, stata

In my mind this should be the same thing but it is not! These two blocks of code don't come to the same result and I don't know why.

The only difference is how I phrased the `if` condition, so it boils down to whether

```
command var if v1 & v2 ==1
```

and

```
command var if v1==1 & v2==1
```

are the same.

Below is my original code. Everything is copy pasted except for the `if` condition.

```
forvalues i = 35/99 {
 
 if inlist(`i', 45, 50, 61, 68, 72, 88) continue 
 
  recode A`i'_a A`i'_b A`i'_c  (.=0) if A`i'_a  &  A`i'_b   & A`i'_c 
 }
```

**is not the same as**

```
 forvalues i = 35/99 {
 
 if inlist(`i', 45, 50, 61, 68, 72, 88) continue 
 
  recode A`i'_a A`i'_b A`i'_c  (.=0) if A`i'_a==.   &  A`i'_b==.    & A`i'_c==. 
}
```

after I run

```
forvalues i = 1/99 {
 
 if inlist(`i', 45, 50, 56, 57, 58, 61, 68 , 72) continue
 
 drop if  A`i'_a==. | A`i'_b==. | A`i'_c==. 
 
}
```

I count the observations, and they are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if vl` is true if `vl` is not zero. That could include missing values.

`if vl == 1` is true if and only if `vl` is 1.

Note also that `if v1 & v2 == 1` is not understood as a contraction of `if v1 == 1 & v2 == 1`.

Note also this technique:

```
. numlist "36/93"

. local possible `r(numlist)'

. local exclude 45 50 61 68 72 88

. local wanted : list possible - exclude

. di "`wanted'"
36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 46 47 48 49 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 62 63 64 65 66 67 69 70 71 73 74
75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 89 90 91 92 93
```

Then the technique would be to loop, say

```
foreach w of local wanted {

}
```

Comment: Ah ok, my data has lots of zeros and lots of missings, so the two lines `drop if var1 & var2 == 1`  and the line `drop if var1==1 & var2 == 1`  are not the same in my case.  So in any if condition, if I just write the variable-name without any specification like ==1 or >2, all it means is the variable !=0 ?

Comment: That's correct. See e.g. https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/  or https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1601600117

Comment: Thanks so much! Also thanks for the technique to consider, but I don't understand how it would help me, I thought forvalues only works with consecutive numbers

Comment: You need to switch to foreach.

Comment: Please see latest edit.